# Static IP address for full node

Tags: iri-node, node, static-ip

I would like to setup a full node, but it appears I need to contact my ISP and establish a static IP.

Has anyone created a full node with or without a static IP address?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Static IP is the best solution if you can get one. If not, a workaround could be using a dynamic DNS service that creates a (sub)domain that always points to your IP address and is automatically updated using a tool on your computer/server. Some of the Dynamic DNS services you could use are:

- [NoIP](https://www.noip.com/free)
- [freedns.afraid.org](http://freedns.afraid.org) (if you wish to use your own domain name)

Comment: As the questioner does not seem to know about dynDNS services, I'd like to add that those services are best to setup on the router itself not via software (in case the router supports dynDNS of course).

Comment: I had no knowledge about dynDNS.  I'll attempt setup with my Netgear router:  https://kb.netgear.com/64/How-do-I-setup-Dynamic-DNS-using-my-DynDNS-account